# How to debug multiple sessions in PHP?

Tags: php, debugging, session, xdebug, zend-debugger

I am working on a project where the application creates web service requests to the same application over the network in development mode to get bogus data and better development environment.

Sometimes when I am debugging I found it hard to do because it seems that XDebug does not work when you have two debugging sessions at the same time on the same PHP installation.

Is there a way to debug multiple sessions in PHP with some debug tool? I have been using Netbeans and XDebug and the debugging just dies as soon as a new session is started. I guess the IDE also has to support multiple sessions. I recently switched to phpStorm so I guess I will give it a go when I'm not lazy.

Comment: Hmmm, tough one. You could try using Zend Server CE as a debugger

Answer (score 1):

Try Eclipse PDT + Zend Server. I think it let you Debug with multiple running processes.

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm uses FIFO queue to manage incoming debugger connections and allows to handle several debug connections simultaneously.
Details - http://blogs.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/03/configure-php-debugging-in-phpstorm-2-0/

Comment: They allow simultaneous connections now: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/04/simultaneous-debugging-sessions-in-phpstorm/